# Python-spidermonkey: How to get a line num. of error

Tags: javascript, python

How to retrieve the line number in which a error occured?

In the next script the line outputs (as the result of the last **raise**) but there is no line num. in JSError object.

```
from spidermonkey import Runtime, JSError

runtime = Runtime()
context = runtime.new_context()

try:
    context.execute( "function test(){ return 'OK' }; \n\ntest2()" )
except JSError as e:
    print "ERROR!"
    print "args = {0}".format( e.args )
    print "message = {0}".format( e.message )
    print "__dict__ = {0}".format( e.__dict__ )
    raise
```

The result:

```
ERROR!
args = ('ReferenceError: test2 is not defined',)
message = ReferenceError: test2 is not defined
__dict__ = {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    context.execute( "function test(){ return 'OK' }; \n\ntest2()" )
  File "<anonymous JavaScript>", line 3, in JavaScript code
spidermonkey.JSError: ReferenceError: test2 is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need a line number, you can retrieve it from [traceback.extract_tb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) function.

```
import sys, traceback
from spidermonkey import Runtime, JSError

runtime = Runtime()
context = runtime.new_context()

try:
    context.execute( "function test(){ return 'OK' }; \n\ntest2()" )
except JSError as e:
    info = sys.exc_info()

    print "ERROR!"
    for file, lineno, function, text in traceback.extract_tb(info[2]):
        print "line #", lineno, ": ", text
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably we can make the next hack:

```
from spidermonkey import Runtime, JSError
import traceback # need to get text of exception
import sys

runtime = Runtime()
context = runtime.new_context()

try:
    context.execute( "function test(){ return 'OK' }; \n\ntest2()" )
except JSError as e:
    print "ERROR!"
    """print "args = {0}".format( e.args )
    print "message = {0}".format( e.message )
    print "__dict__ = {0}".format( e.__dict__ )"""

    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print "traceback='{0}'".format( traceback.format_exc() ) # we can parse it to get a line
```

If you know more elegant method please publish it.